# My bluetooth keyboard keeps losing connection for just a second or two

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

My wireless keyboard keeps losing connectivity for a few seconds but then connects back fine. This happens sporadically so I can't figure out if something particular is causing this. This will happen several times in a row over a short period before connecting and staying connected for several days. My wireless mouse never loses connection. My wireless keyboard is located right in front and slightly below my iMac. I'm running Sierra with the Apple wireless keyboard. Keyboard has new batteries and shows 70% charged.

Comment: Did you try to remove your Apple wireless keyboard in macOS System preferences > Bluetooth? Than add your keyboard again. Does it resolve the issue?

Answer (score -3):

Go to system preferences, sharing, bluetooth, advanced settings.

Comment: Then what? My keyboard shows up as connected and when I hit advanced I get a box with 3 options. All three are checked but don't appear related to my problem.